# Msgraph - upload large files using typeScript

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, email-attachments

I have a method to upload large files called `uploadLargeAttachment` for some reasons its failed all the time with error code 503

here is my method

```
public static maxAttachmentBytes = Math.pow(1024, 2) * 3;
 private async getAuthHeaders() {
    const token = await this.getAccessToken();
    return {
      authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    };
  }

      public async uploadLargeAttachment(
        inbox: string,
        messageId: string,
        attachment: MSGraph.UploadAttachmentData
      ) {
        let content = Buffer.from(attachment.contentBytes, "base64");
        const session = await this.axios.post(
          `users/${inbox}/messages/${messageId}/attachments/createUploadSession`,
          {
            AttachmentItem: {
              attachmentType: "file",
              name: attachment.name,
              size: attachment.size,
            },
          },
          {
            headers: await this.getAuthHeaders(),
          }
        );
    
        let start = 0;
        try {
          while (content.byteLength > 0) {
            const bytes = Math.min(
              EmailRepository.maxAttachmentBytes,
              content.byteLength
            );
            const result = await this.axios.put(
              session.data.uploadUrl,
              content.slice(0, bytes),
              {
                // maxContentLength: Infinity,
                headers: {
                  "Content-Range": `bytes ${start}-${start + bytes - 1}/${
                    attachment.size
                  }`,
                  "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
                  "Content-Length": bytes,
                  "Retry-After": 5, --> this second try
                },
              }
            );
            if (result.data.NextExpectedRanges) {
              start = parseInt(result.data.NextExpectedRanges[0]);
            }
            content = content.slice(bytes);
          }
        } catch (error) {
          await this.axios.delete(session.data.uploadUrl);
          throw error;
        }
      }
```

my tries to fix the issue
1- decrease `maxAttachmentBytes`
2- I added  `"Retry-After": 5,`
but still failed
what I am missing

Error Log

```
Error: Request failed with status code 503
    at createError (/Users/minafawzy/Documents/TechModgroup/BDS-API/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (/Users/minafawzy/Documents/TechModgroup/BDS-API/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/Users/minafawzy/Documents/TechModgroup/BDS-API/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:236:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1220:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

Comment: HTTP error 503 tells that the service is unavailable. I would try the same call with MS Graph Explorer or POSTMAN against the same tenant and see it works or not; also you can try uploading small attachments

Comment: Thanks but that was because of NextExpectedRanges was written wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was miss spelling `NextExpectedRanges`
I fixed like that

```
 if (result.data.nextExpectedRanges) {
              start = parseInt(result.data.nextExpectedRanges[0]);
            }
```